# How should I combine $(document).ready statements?

Tags: jquery

Is it appropriate to combine all functions that wouldn't conflict into one

```
$(document).ready(function) {
});
```

or

```
$(function() {
});
```

call to save a couple lines?

Comment: Not sure if it's appropriate or not, but I combine them often.

Comment: Multiple `ready` handlers is not good practice.

Comment: @SimpleCoder and @JungleFreak - thx, what I wanted to hear.

Answer (score 4):

To jQuery, it makes no difference whether to use one big `.ready()` handler, or call it several times. Internally, they all got merged together anyway or will get fired instantly when the `DOM` is ready already.

In my opinion, it's not a good practice to have more than one `.ready()` handler. Its like asking for confusion.